# Why is let not the same as var in this case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently saw a post saying never use `var` in JavaScript (ECMAScript6).  Always use `const` or `let` instead.  I have the following code snippet from the YouTube API docs that uses `var`.

```
function changeBorderColor(playerStatus) {
    var color;
    if (playerStatus == -1) {
        color = "#37474F"; // unstarted = gray
    } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
        color = "#FFFF00"; // ended = yellow
    } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
        color = "#33691E"; // playing = green
    } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
        color = "#DD2C00"; // paused = red
    } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
        color = "#AA00FF"; // buffering = purple
    } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
        color = "#FF6DOO"; // video cued = orange
    }
    if (color) {
        document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = color;
    }
}
```

When I change `var color` to `let color`, my linter suggests that the line near the bottom (`if (color)`) will always evaluate to true.  That is "condition is always true".  I'm having trouble understanding what `let` causes the behavior and `var` does not.

Comment: try `let color = null;`

Comment: @charlietfl that solves the problem, but not really my question of why var and let are different in this case.

Comment: I think the linter is wrong to be honest

Comment: @charlietfl Me too. I was looking for a polite way to say it. The linter may be confused by the so-many blocks there that assign a value to `color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter is just wrong.

The last `if (color)` is not affected at all by whether you use `let color` or `var color`.  It's only affected by whether any of the `if` tests for `playerStatus` hit their conditions.

As others have said, you can probably work around the linter bug by assigning a default value to `color` as in `let color = null;` and that will likely avoid the confusion the linter got itself in.